# MudBlazor DataGrid columns added from code are not valid

Tags: datagrid, mudblazor

I want to use MudDataGrid with columns that are added from code, but like in the example the columns are always added at the end no matter what is in the grid. in the example play with the 2 buttons on top to see the problem. What can it be, any ideas?

```
<MudButton OnClick="(()=>LoadDays(10))">Load 10</MudButton>
<MudButton OnClick="(()=>LoadDays(1))">Load 1</MudButton>
<MudDataGrid Class="main-container-grid" Dense=true Height="100%" ColumnsPanelReordering=false DragIndicatorSize=Size.Small T=DateOnly Items=@ListOfDays Hover=true Virtualize=true RowsPerPage=10000 FixedHeader=true Striped=true Bordered=true ColumnResizeMode="ResizeMode.Column">
    <Columns>
        <TemplateColumn Title="employee" StickyLeft=true>
            <CellTemplate>
                xx
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
        @foreach (DateOnly day in ListOfDays)
        {
            <TemplateColumn Sortable="false" HeaderClass="date-info-header" Class="date-info" CellClass="date-info-cell">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <div class="head-content">
                        <div class="day-number">@day.ToString("dd-MM")</div>
                        <div class="day-name">@day.ToString("ddd")</div>
                    </div>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <CellTemplate>
                    <span>0</span>

                </CellTemplate>
            </TemplateColumn>
        }
    </Columns>
    <NoRecordsContent>
        No data
    </NoRecordsContent>
</MudDataGrid>

@code {
    private List<DateOnly> ListOfDays { get; set; } = new List<DateOnly>();



    private void LoadDays(int count)
    {
        ListOfDays = new List<DateOnly>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            ListOfDays.Add(DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i)));   
        }
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOmyEREzQZGBPalz

Comment: Looks like a `MudDataGrid` bug or "missing feature" I opened this [pull request](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/8288) on their repository which fixes this issue.